# Clear file contents in haskell language

Tags: haskell

How to clear all the file contents in haskell.?Can anyone help this,I want to remove all the data from a text file and make it empty.Is their any function to do so?

Or can i make any such function?

Answer (score 7):

You can write nothing on the file, overwriting what was there before.

```
main = writeFile yourFile ""
```

But is this really what you want to do?

Comment: Is this sufficient to remove all of the content inside it?

Comment: @user3001932 Yes, `writeFile` uses write mode, not append mode, so it completely overwrites the contents of the file.