# Haskell: Clear file contents using an open handle

Tags: haskell, io, handle

In Haskell, how can one clear a file's contents when you already have an open file handle and do not wish to close it?  Is there some easy way that isn't apparent to me from the System.IO API?

In a less restrictive situation, the easiest way to clear a file's contents is with `writeFile awesomefile.txt ""`.  If you already have an open file handle to `awesomefile.txt` though, then `writeFile` will fail with an exception (namely "openFile: resource busy (file is locked)").

I thought perhaps using `hSeek` to set the handle back to the start position might have a similiar effect, but it doesn't.  After seeking the handle back to the start, the next `hPutStr` call will just overwrite as many bytes as necessary (which makes more logical sense anyway).

The situation comes up in my program where I want to very frequently write information to a file for logging purposes.  Only the most recent log data is relevant (and gigantic files are very inconvenient), so the file is emptied before each write.  Because writes are so frequent, I would like to only open the file handle once.

only related question:
[Clear file contents in haskell language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062595/clear-file-contents-in-haskell-language)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`hSetFileSize`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetFileSize) to truncate a file to a given size.

Comment: This is the solution I was hoping for.  It is worth noting for the 'frequent writes into a log file' situation that `hSetFileSize hdl n` seems to be faster if `n` is small but not zero